# Display a very large grid table in R-Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, large-data, r-grid, gtable

I want to display a large grid table in Shiny but I can't find a way to do it, as Shiny seems to always truncate my table. The reason why I use a grid table is the fact that it provides some features I need to implement into my table. I managed to display the right-left view but top-bottom view is always truncated. Here is my code :

ui:

```
library(shiny)
library(gridExtra)
library(grid)
library(gtable)

shinyUI(fluidPage(
mainPanel(
  div(class="double-scroll",style='overflow-x:scroll;overflow-y:scroll;
      height:1600px; width:1600px;',plotOutput("out"))
         )
       ))
```

server:

```
shinyServer(function(input, output,session) {
mat <- matrix(8,nrow=50,ncol=50)
example <- tableGrob(mat,rows=NULL,cols=NULL)
output$out <- renderPlot({grid.draw(example)})
             })
```

In this example, the 50 columns of "8" are shown but only 20 rows are displayed.

Answer (score 0):

Try a code like that:

```
 ui <- fluidPage(
     sidebarLayout(
     sidebarPanel(
          fileInput("file1", "Choose CSV File",
                accept = c("text/csv",
                "text/comma-separated-values,text/plain",
                ".csv")
    ),
    tags$hr(),
    checkboxInput("header", "Header", TRUE)
  ),
  mainPanel(
    tableOutput("contents")
  )
)
)

   server <- function(input, output) {
     output$contents <- renderTable({
     inFile <- input$file1
     if (is.null(inFile))
    return(NULL)
    df <- read.csv(inFile$datapath, header = input$header)
    print(df[,c(1:16)]) # display only the first 16th columns of your dataset
 })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```